# Script dies without any information why - difference in Python versions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Maybe a little stupid headline, but I can't explain it better.

I have a script which extracts files from files recursively. At the very top there is a zip file, which contains a bunch of gzipped files. Each of these gzip-files contain a tar-file, and finally this tar-file contains the data files I want to get. Don't ask me whoever created this structure, I can't change it and I have to deal with.

I wrote a script which does the job recursively and very generic. I use python-magic to determine the type of the file and when it is a zip, gzip or tar I call the same function again with the filename as parameter. Nothing serious.

So far so good. The problem is that the script dies - without any notice. I just see the line `[1]    49050 killed`. That's it. I investigated the problem now for hours and I know that the script used to work - with Python 3.8+. After having no more ideas I ran the same script with Python 3.6 - and it dies. Well, I guess I got the guilty one.

I'm a little bit confused because the code does not change and except python-magic I only use system library modules. So, my question is, if there's really such a difference with recursion between these two Python versions? Is this somehow related to the memory management between them? Any hints on how to maybe fix such an issue? The problem is that the server which it should run on only has Python 3.6 on it and there's no chance to get a newer version installed. :(

Comment: Generally Python doesn't just die, it gets an exception and prints an exception trace.

Comment: Memory problems or corrupted notebook.

Comment: The operating system can kill the process if it takes too much memory. As in all of it. So you could observe the memory usage using system tools while it runs (top on unix like systems, task manager in windows). Maybe 3.8 has optimizations that make it use less memory.

Comment: I would push harder to get Python upgraded. 3.6 is long past end-of-life.

Comment: Well, I tried to beat some information out of the logs, but even `dmesg` did not show any reason. And unfortunately there's no exception either (which surprises me even more). I also tried to observe with top as suggested, no success. It's really a pain in the a**. :/ It seems that I have to write a workaround for my extraction problem.

Comment: I tried now several Python versions on different machines and all I see is, that Python 3.6 seems to have a problem with recursion (or at least the way I do a recursion). Either the script gets killed or it simply runs through, but stops to call the function itself again (it calls recursively the function at the beginning but stops somewhere randomly). Recursion limit is the same as on Python 3.8, `1000`. I have to look for a different, weird solution. :(